# Как восстановить самоудаляющееся письмо из Cookies?

Tags: кодировка, cookie, восстановление

Здравствуйте!

Получил самоудаляющееся письмо. Произошла ошибка и оно закрылось, а там важная информация!

Я нашёл данные cookies о нём. Можно ли как-нибудь расшифровать их?

Comment: Может, не coocies,  а cookies? И где такие самоудаляющиеся письма? Какой сервис? Какой почтовый клиент?

Comment: @KoVadim, скорее всего, имеется в виду сервис privnote. Вкратце: первый человек оставляет сообщение и получает ссылку. Второй человек открывает ссылку (в это время сообщение стирается с сервера) и получает нужную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Если сервис исчезающих писем сделан хоть немного разумно, то по кукам восстановить письмо, к сожалению, не получится.